# My subclass as a property won't accept new values for its properties

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiviewcontroller, exc-bad-access

I `have a UIViewController` that presents another `UIViewController` with a picker and returns four values.  I also have a custom class called Chemical that can hold these values.  In the delegate method that receives the values (the `didSelectSource` one in `AdjustViewController`) I put a breakpoint and I can see that the proper values come back, but when I try to assign them to my local `Chemical` called `selectedChemical`, the values don't stick and I get an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.  When I hover over the `selectedChemical.chemName` it says, "out of scope".

I don't get it.

---

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Chemical : NSObject {

    NSString *chemName;
    NSString *chemConcentration;
    float chemConstant;
    BOOL chemIsLiquid;  
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *chemName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *chemConcentration;
@property float chemConstant;
@property BOOL chemIsLiquid;    

- (id)initWithChemical:(NSString *)chemical 
      andConcentration:(NSString *)concentration 
           andConstant:(float)constant 
           andIsLiquid:(BOOL)isLiquid;
@end
```

---

```
#import "Chemical.h"


@implementation Chemical

@synthesize chemName;
@synthesize chemConcentration;
@synthesize chemConstant;
@synthesize chemIsLiquid;   

- (id)initWithChemical:(NSString *)chemical 
      andConcentration:(NSString *)concentration 
           andConstant:(float)constant 
           andIsLiquid:(BOOL)isLiquid {

    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.chemName = chemical;
        self.chemConcentration = concentration;
        self.chemConstant = constant;
        self.chemIsLiquid = isLiquid;
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

---

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SourcePickerViewController.h"
#import "Chemical.h"

@interface AdjustViewController : UIViewController <SourcePickerViewControllerDelegate>{
// IB controls  
    UITextField *sourceField;
    UITextField *volumeField;
    UILabel *startingLabel;
    UILabel *targetLabel;
    UITextView *adviceLabel;
// Setup variables for the kind of chemical 
    int numberOfComponents;
    NSDictionary *dictionaryOfSources;
// Local ivars  
    float percentRemove;
    float gallonsRemove;
    float selectedChemSourceAmount;
    int delta;
    NSString *selectedChemName;
    NSString *selectedChemConcentration;
    float selectedChemConstant;
    BOOL selectedChemIsLiquid;
    NSString *compositeName;
    NSString *messageBody;
    NSString *adviceMessage;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *sourceField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *volumeField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *startingLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *targetLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextView *adviceLabel;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedChemName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *selectedChemConcentration;
@property float selectedChemConstant;
@property BOOL selectedChemIsLiquid;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *compositeName;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *messageBody;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *adviceMessage;

@property int numberOfComponents;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *dictionaryOfSources;

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)startingSliderChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)startingSliderFinishedChanging;
- (IBAction)targetSliderChanged:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)targetSliderFinishedChanging;
- (IBAction)getChemicalSource;
- (void)updateAdvice;

@end
```

---

```
#import "AdjustViewController.h"

@implementation AdjustViewController

@synthesize sourceField;
@synthesize volumeField;
@synthesize startingLabel;
@synthesize targetLabel;
@synthesize adviceLabel;
@synthesize numberOfComponents;
@synthesize dictionaryOfSources;
@synthesize compositeName;
@synthesize messageBody;
@synthesize adviceMessage;
@synthesize selectedChemName;
@synthesize selectedChemConcentration;
@synthesize selectedChemConstant;
@synthesize selectedChemIsLiquid;

- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender {
    [sourceField resignFirstResponder];
    [volumeField resignFirstResponder];
    [self updateAdvice];
}

- (IBAction)startingSliderChanged:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    int progressAsInt = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
    NSString *newValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", progressAsInt];
    startingLabel.text = newValue;
    [newValue release];
}

- (IBAction)targetSliderChanged:(id)sender {
    UISlider *slider = (UISlider *)sender;
    int progressAsInt = (int)(slider.value + 0.5f);
    NSString *newValue = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d", progressAsInt];
    targetLabel.text = newValue;
    [newValue release];
}

- (IBAction)startingSliderFinishedChanging {
//  [self updateAdvice];
}

- (IBAction)targetSliderFinishedChanging {
//  [self updateAdvice];
}


// Present the picker for chlorine selection
- (IBAction)getChemicalSource {
    SourcePickerViewController *sourcePickerViewController = [[SourcePickerViewController alloc] init];
    sourcePickerViewController.delegate = self;
    NSLog(@"getChemicalSource setting numberOfComponents %d", self.numberOfComponents);
    sourcePickerViewController.numberOfComponents = self.numberOfComponents;
    NSLog(@"getChemicalSource sending numberOfComponents %d", sourcePickerViewController.numberOfComponents);
    sourcePickerViewController.dictionaryOfSources = self.dictionaryOfSources;
    [self presentModalViewController:sourcePickerViewController animated:YES];
    [sourcePickerViewController release];
}


- (void)updateAdvice {
    NSLog(@"--updateAdvice");
    NSLog(@"  selectedChemical name = %@", selectedChemName);
    NSLog(@"  selectedChemical concentration = %@", selectedChemConcentration);
    NSLog(@"  selectedChemical constant = %1.6f", selectedChemConstant);
    NSLog(@"  selectedChemical is liquid = %d", selectedChemIsLiquid);
// First check to see if there is a source AND volume, otherwise prompt user to enter them
    if ([volumeField.text isEqualToString:@""] || [sourceField.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
        adviceMessage = @"Enter a source and volume.";
}
// If there IS a source and volume, calculate!
    else {
        if ([selectedChemConcentration isEqualToString:@""]) { // If there's no concentration, make a string with just the name
            compositeName = selectedChemName;
            NSLog(@"  compositeName without concentration = %@", compositeName);
        }
        else { // But if there is a concentration, make a string with the name and concentration and a space between.
            compositeName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@", selectedChemName, selectedChemConcentration];
            NSLog(@"  compositeName with concentration = %@", compositeName);
        }
        delta = [targetLabel.text intValue] - [startingLabel.text intValue]; // The difference between target and starting levels
        NSLog(@"  delta = %d", delta);
        selectedChemSourceAmount = delta * [volumeField.text intValue] * selectedChemConstant; // Calculates the amount of source chemical necessary in ounces
        NSLog(@"  selectedChemSourceAmount = %1.1f", selectedChemSourceAmount);

// If delta is positive, add chemical
        if (delta > 0) {
            NSLog(@">> Delta > 0");
            if (selectedChemIsLiquid) {
                if (selectedChemSourceAmount > 128) { // Amount is more than a gallon
                    selectedChemSourceAmount = selectedChemSourceAmount / 128;
                    messageBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"To increase %@ by %d ppm, add %1.1f gal of ", self.title, delta, selectedChemSourceAmount]; 
                }
                else { // Less than a gallon
                    messageBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"To increase %@ by %d ppm, add %1.1f fl oz of ", self.title, delta, selectedChemSourceAmount];
                }
            }
            else { // Chemical is a solid
                if (selectedChemSourceAmount > 16) { // Amount is more than a pound
                    selectedChemSourceAmount = selectedChemSourceAmount / 16;
                    messageBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"To increase %@ by %d ppm, add %1.1f lb of ", self.title, delta, selectedChemSourceAmount]; 
                }
                else { // Less than a pound
                    messageBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"To increase %@ by %d ppm, add %1.1f oz of ", self.title, delta, selectedChemSourceAmount];
                }
            }
            adviceMessage = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@.", messageBody, compositeName];
        }
// If delta is zero, stay the course
        if (delta == 0) {
            NSLog(@"== Delta = 0");
            adviceMessage = @"You're on target.  No action necessary.";
        }
// If delta is negative, remove water   
        if (delta < 0) {
            NSLog(@"<< Delta < 0");
            adviceMessage = @"You're over target.  Remove some water.";
    }

    }
    adviceLabel.text = adviceMessage; // Set the advice label
    [messageBody release]; // And get rid of message
    [compositeName release];
    [adviceMessage release];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"AdjustViewController launched");
    sourceField.text = @"";
    adviceLabel.text = @"";
    percentRemove = 0;
    gallonsRemove = 0;
    delta = 0;
    selectedChemSourceAmount = 0;
//  [self updateAdvice];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    sourceField = nil;
    volumeField = nil;
    startingLabel = nil;
    targetLabel = nil;
    adviceLabel = nil;
    dictionaryOfSources = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [sourceField release];
    [volumeField release];
    [startingLabel release];
    [targetLabel release];
    [adviceLabel release];
    [dictionaryOfSources release];
    [super dealloc];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Picker View Delegate Methods

// Returns the values from the picker if a source was chosen
- (void)sourcePickerViewController:(SourcePickerViewController *)controller 
                   didSelectSource:(NSString *)source 
                  andConcentration:(NSString *)concentration 
                       andConstant:(float)constant 
                       andIsLiquid:(BOOL)isLiquid {

    selectedChemName = source;
    selectedChemConcentration = concentration;
    selectedChemConstant = constant;
    selectedChemIsLiquid = isLiquid;

//   Update the source textfield.  If concentration is empty, just use the source otherwise concatenate them        
    if ([selectedChemConcentration isEqualToString:@""]) {
        sourceField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", selectedChemName];
    }
    else    {
        sourceField.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ %@", selectedChemName, selectedChemConcentration];
    }
//    [self updateAdvice];
    NSLog(@"Returned source = %@, concentration = %@, constant = %1.7f, isLiquid = %d", source, concentration, constant, isLiquid);
    NSLog(@"selectedChemical.chemName = %@, chemConcentration = %@, chemConstant = %1.7f, chemIsLiquid = %d", selectedChemName, selectedChemConcentration, selectedChemConstant, selectedChemIsLiquid);
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

// Returns from the picker without choosing a new source
- (void)sourcePickerViewController:(SourcePickerViewController *)controller 
                   didSelectCancel:(BOOL)didCancel {
//  [self updateAdvice];
    NSLog(@"Returned without selecting source");
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems that won't end up solving this

1. As mentioned, your init needs to call [super init]
2. Classes that have retained properties need a dealloc message that sets them to nil

And some things that might help

1. What is messageBody? You release it, but it only is allocated if delta > 0.  You should only release if you alloc.  Use this and you don't need to release

   ```
   messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"To increase %@ by %dppm, add %1.1f gal of ", self.title, delta, sourceAmount];
   ```
2. Same with compositeName -- sometimes you alloc and sometimes you assign from a property.  You should only release if you alloc or retain (or call a method that does that for you).  Use stringWithFormat in the else, and don't release
3. Same with adviceMessage -- sometimes you alloc, and sometimes not, but you always release.

Please read this to learn the memory rules for iPhone:

http://loufranco.com/blog/files/managing-memory-iphone.html

I also wrote this to help people debug EXC_BAD_ACCESS

http://loufranco.com/blog/files/Understanding-EXC_BAD_ACCESS.html

Comment: @Lou, thank you for the answer!  I know I don't have a full grip on this memory management thing.  I updated the question with the full contents of the two classes.  FYI, `messageBody` and `compositeName` are strings I use to build a final message called `adviceMessage` whose only job is to update a textfield in my UI.  What it contains is what all the if-then-ing is about.  So, is it ok to `initWithFormat` a string that I haven't `alloc`ed?  
If it's a property?  And if I don't `alloc` it, I don't `release` it?

Comment: Well, I quickly changed all the `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:`s to `[NSString stringWithFormat:` and got rid of the three `release`s at the end of `updateAdvice` and lo and behold, no crashes - at least yet!  I'm leaving on vacation today, so I'm done coding for two weeks, but now I have a build to show my family that doesn't crash.  Thanks again for the advice.  Oh, and I started looking at your articles and they look like just what I need to keep learning!

Comment: The three biggest things that will help you are: always run a "Build and Analyze" and fix everything it says. Check for leaks with Instruments and if you crash try the NSZombieEnabled setting.  The rest of the article has other things to try, but those are easy and effective.

Comment: I have made Build & Analyze a habit, but obviously it doesn't catch everything.  I've just played with Instruments a few times and don't see how to translate seeing a leak into finding where it's happening.  Is the NSZombieEnabled setting in Instruments or Xcode?

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling `[super init]`.

Your `init` method should look something like this:

```
- (id)initWithChemical:(NSString *)chemical 
      andConcentration:(NSString *)concentration 
           andConstant:(float)constant 
           andIsLiquid:(BOOL)isLiquid {

    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.chemName = chemical;
        self.chemConcentration = concentration;
        self.chemConstant = constant;
        self.chemIsLiquid = isLiquid;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also, I don't see where you're instantiating your `Chemical` instance variable. Make sure that is instantiated before assigning properties.

Comment: Thanks - do you have a suggestion for where I should instantiate it?  Could I do it in `viewDidLoad`? I get a little confused - I declared `Chemical *selectedChemical` in the header and synthesized it.  Do I then do something like `Chemical *selectedChemical = [[Chemical alloc] init...]` in the implementation somewhere?

Comment: I don't see any difference to your answer - am I missing something?

Comment: I also updated my question with another method that's in `AdjustViewController` called `- (void)updateAdvice` which is where I need the data from the `Chemical` object I'm (trying) to make.  The way I have it written, I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` when I look at `selectedChemical.chemConcentration` in the delegate method.  If I declare it there (it's commented out now) I get a `Local declaration of 'selectedChemical' hides instance variable`

Comment: I added four properties to my view controller and was able to assign the returned values to them (but not my custom class) and they now appear available in my `-(void)updateAdvice` method.  But if I pause the program in that method, even though the `NSLogs` at the beginning show that they are set right, hovering on them further in gets an `out of scope` description.